# Number of bits needed for Huffman code

Tags: probability, cryptography

Jake uses a Huffman code to compress i.i.d. (independent nad identically distributed) strings of symbols that come from a 5-ary alphabet ($A$, $B$, $E$, $R$, $S$) where the probabilities of occurrence of the symbols are given by ($1/4$, $1/4$, $1/6$, $1/6$, $1/6$) respectively. How many bits does his encoder need to encode the string "BEARS"?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? The more information you can give us, the more easily we'll be able to tailor our answers to your needs (and the more likely that people will try to give you an answer).

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on, to be honest. Are we like randomly drawing letters? If that's the case, then we can't give a specific amount of needed bits, due to uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

You have been given the letters and their probabilities. Construct a [Huffman code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) for them. With this code, how many bits are needed to encode "BEARS".